# Assign proper fill factor option for each index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use `SQL Server` and want to assign proper fill factor value for each indexes. I know below parameter for each index:

1. Row count of each table
2. Amount of Scan occurred for each index
3. Amount of Seek occurred for each index
4. Amount of lookup occurred for each index.
5. Amount of update occurred for each index.

I know that scan, seek and lookup raise fill factor value to 100 and update down fill factor to 0. but I look for a formula for calculate proper fill factor option according to above parameter of each table.

**EDIT**

I use below script to get above parameters :

```
select  SCHEMA_NAME(B.schema_id)+'.'+B.name+' \ '+C.name AS IndexName,
        A.user_scans,
        A.user_seeks,
        A.user_lookups, 
        A.user_updates, 
        D.rowcnt,
        C.fill_factor
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats A
INNER JOIN sys.objects B ON A.object_id = B.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes C ON C.object_id = B.object_id AND C.index_id = A.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes D ON D.id = B.object_id AND D.indid = A.index_id
```

**Edit 2**
I use below reference for best value for fill factor option :

[Best value for fill factor 1](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/beginning-sql-server-one-step-at-a-time-blog-43/net-framework/what-is-the-best-value-for-the-fill-factor---index-fill-factor-and-performance--part-2-139448)

[Best value for fill factor 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/juggling_with_sql/2011/06/13/what-is-the-best-value-for-fill-factor-in-sql-server/)

Comment: What makes you think you need to change the default fill factor to start with? What problems have you observed, what measurements have you done?

Comment: fill factor value have direct effect on performance. I want to assign proper fill factor value to have better performance.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What did you measure? How do you know you have the wrong fill factor? **If I tell you to put full factor 42, how will you measure the impact?**. You are chasing red herring.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: Please see my edit.

Comment: Depends how fragmented the index gets and how frequently you are able to schedule index maintenance. Have a look at Paul Randal's MCM video on index fragmentation.

Comment: My question remains unanswered. What have you measured? How do you know you have a fill factor problem?

Comment: I've got no measurement, just based on what I've read about fill factors, I believe that frequently updated indices should have a fill factor less than 100, so page splits and subsequently, index pages with 50% fill factor are avoided. Is that wrong?

Comment: Any modification you want to do which is not backed by root cause analysis and metrics is wrong. Page splits are easy to measure with [Page Splits/sec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177426.aspx) & [leaf_allocations_count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) provided you understand that tail inserts are technically splits. And you do understand that fill factor affects *only* index creation and changing the fill factor to an existing index is a no-op, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the technique described by Kendra Little from Brent Ozar Unlimited.
[Here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/) is the article. She describes her methodology for finding and addressing fill factor issues.

Also as Remus mentioned in his comments, you should use discretion when messing with the fill factor. I realize a lot of articles on the internet make it sound as though a high fill factor will cause a innumerable page splits and ruin your performance, but lowering the fill factor can cause more problems than it solves.

Kendra suggests using the default fill factor and tracking fragmentation over time, and only when an index appears to have a fragmentation issue due to page splits, should you slowly decrease the fill factor. I've been using this technique and I've noticed a much better use of my cache because of how much less my indexes are needlessly inflated.

*"I frequently find that people have put a fillfactor setting of 80 or below on all the indexes in a database. This can waste many GB of space on disk and in memory. This wasted space causes extra trips to storage, and the whole thing drags down the performance of your queries."*

Check out this quote in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459%28v=sql.90%29.aspx): *“For example, a fill factor value of 50 can cause database read performance to decrease by two times. “*

So in a nice way of saying it. I'm not sure that you should start needlessly messing with the fill factor. Observer, study, then act.